# Check a checkbox on Full Gridview row click using Javascript in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am able to check a column of checkbox when I click the gridview row, however it limits only to a particluar column, when I click on the column of the checkbox, it it is not wkorking.

Here's the case, When I click the any where on this part, it worked well. the checkbox still checking.

[image]

but when I click on this part, it doesn't work already.

[image]

codes are here

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', 'tr.dataRow', function () {
        var checked = $(this).find('input[id*=chkBusinessSelected]').prop('checked');
         $(this).find('input[id*=chkBusinessSelected]').prop('checked', !checked);

    });
});

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function () {
    $('body').on('click', 'tr.dataRow', function () {
        var checked = $(this).find('input[id*=chkBusinessSelected]').prop('checked');
        $(this).find('input[id*=chkBusinessSelected]').prop('checked', !checked);

    });
});
```

---

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdBusiness" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" Width="420px"  ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No records Found" OnRowDataBound="grdBusiness_RowDataBound" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"    >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBusinessSelected" runat="server"  />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Code" HeaderText="Code" SortExpression="Code" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Business Type" HeaderText="Business Type" SortExpression="Business Type" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#90FF90" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black"  />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
</asp:GridView>
```

---

```
 protected void grdBusiness_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
         e.Row.CssClass = "dataRow";     
     }
 }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: to have a real FULL gridview row that is able to check the checkbox, as of now the codes are only able to do that on the 2nd and 3rd column. checkbox column when click is uable to check itself.

Answer (score 2):

I am edited @UsmanKhalid 's answer and it worked for me:

```
$(function () {
        $("#<%=grdBusiness.ClientID %> td").click(function () {
            selectRow($(this).closest("tr"));
        });
    });

    function selectRow(row) {
        var firstInput = row[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        firstInput.checked = !firstInput.checked;
    }
```

Comment: Should I put anything in the .ascx source page?

Comment: I have a page and gridview in page and this script at the header. At my page it works. By the way are you added Jquery reference to your page or control?

Comment: I see.. my javascript is on external file. I have a user control with Update Panel on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$(function () {
        $("[id*=GridView] td").click(function () {
            selectRow($(this).closest("tr"));
        });
    });

function selectRow(row)
{
    var firstInput = row.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    firstInput.checked = !firstInput.checked;
}
```

Comment: Just replace "[id*=GridView]" with your gridview id.

Comment: should I removed my original Javascript code, and replace yours? or retrain it and yours is just an addtion?

Comment: Yes remove your code. And put your gridid like this : #<%=grdBusiness.ClientID %> td

Comment: I'm sorry I need to remove my vote for this because i found out that this does not fully answers the question, because it still does not click the checkbox, only the column part but the checkbox itself is not checkable.

Comment: @rickyProgrammer change `row.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];` to `row[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];` and try again. It will works. Because `row` is `jquery` variable and `getElementsByTagName` is javascript function.

Comment: @rickyProgrammer Jquery variable javascript variable diference [at this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326719/javascript-variable-using-jquery-to-find-variable) and [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801099/converting-javascript-this-to-jquery-this)

Comment: This is my current codes   $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=grdRP.ClientID %> td").click(function () {
                //$('body').on('click', 'tr.dataRow', function () {
                selectRow($(this).closest("tr"));
            });
        });

          

        function selectRow(row) {
            var firstInput = row[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
            firstInput.checked = !firstInput.checked;
        }

Comment: Still, the full gridview row is able to check the checkbox expect for the checkbox itself in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$('tr.dataRow').click(function(){

  var chkBox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
    chkBox.prop("checked", !chkBox.prop("checked"));

});
```